# slash is missing in the request url for relative path

Tags: nginx

See many errors like below in my nginx error log:

```
2014/03/19 13:27:15 [error] 1599#0: *2486130 open() 
"/var/www/example/bbsimages/apps/icon/record.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), 
client: 183.31.66.27, server: www.example.com, 
Request: "GET /bbsimages/apps/icon/record.png HTTP/1.1", 
host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/bbs/"
```

Obviously, there is a missing slash between "bbs" and "images". But I check the referrer page, and cannot find anywhere it makes a request to bbsimages. How come a slash of root (example.com/bbs/) is missing?

Thanks!

**Note: [3/21]** The site is using base tag:

```
<base <base id="headbase" href="http://www.example.com/bbs/" />
```

Could that be a problem? Some browser (IE6) does not like it?

Comment: so hard to get answer from stackoverflow those days. Maybe questions are overflow???

Comment: Thank you for edit the page by change it to 'example', but hope someone can provide the solution.